# Docker-compose: Install php library via composer in a volume outside app folder

Tags: docker, docker-compose, composer-php

I want to install a php library via composer outside app directory (in /var/www/lib), because app directory is my DOCUMENT_ROOT and is **public**. Also I want to see and edit the composer.json file in this directory locally so I created a volume to /var/www/lib but is empty after the installation.

I create a volume in the docker-compose.yml:

```
volumes:
      - ./app:/var/www/html
      - ./lib:/var/www/lib <==
```

And I install composer and the library in the php/Dockerfile:

```
...
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
RUN mkdir /var/www/lib && cd /var/www/lib && composer require phpoffice/phpspreadsheet
```

No errors shown when I execute docker-compose up but the directory /var/www/lib is empty inside the container and it's empty in my local directory too.

I've been googling and I tried to install the library via command in the docker-compose.yml:

```
command: sh -c "cd /var/www/lib && composer require phpoffice/phpspreadsheet"
```

but my php container exits when I try to start it. I don't see any error in Docker Desktop:
[container log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TUkIc.png)

- What I'm doing wrong?
- Installing the library via command is the best way?
- Is there a way to install the library via Dockerfile in a docker-compose volume?

NOTE: If I install the library in the app directory via `Dockerfile`, the installation is correct. Composer creates the composer.json file and the vendor directory in `/var/www/html`, but I don't want the vendor directory inside `/var/www/html` and I want to see composer.json locally.

Comment: In general I'd recommend keeping all of your code in the image, and not in volumes.  Of note the volume mount will hide anything your Dockerfile does in that directory, which makes it hard to build and test a reusable image.  You already have a `RUN composer ...` Dockerfile command; does deleting the new volume mount help?

Comment: I think it is not a good practice to put the vendor directory inside a public directory. This is the reason why I want to put vendor directory outside

Answer (score 0):

Mmmm you should try to update Dockerfile, with something like this:

```
    RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
    RUN mkdir -p /var/www/lib
    WORKDIR /var/www/lib
```

Also try to change your `yml` file mointing the volumes in this way:

```
    volumes:
      - ./app:/var/www/html
      - ./lib:/var/www/lib
```

Finally try to run your container with this `docker-compose run php sh -c "composer require phpoffice/phpspreadsheet"` and check the container logs during the running process.

Comment: If I do this, the library is installed correctly but I cannot view and edit the composer.json locally. I have to enter the container via console to see and edit the composer.json.

Comment: @JorgeSM try to add `COPY composer.json .` in your Dockerfile and run the compose again with `docker-compose run php`